# Setting up Zend Framework CLI tool on OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: zend-framework, php, include-path

I have been fighting to set up Zend Framework's CLI tool on OS X for ages. I have followed [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html#zend.tool.framework.clitool.setup-starnix), but I can't get it to work.

> The most common setup in the *nix environment, is to copy the zf.sh
>   and zf.php into the same directory as your PHP binary.
>
> [...]
>
> To find out the location of your PHP binary, you can execute 'which
>   php' on the command line. This will return the location of the PHP
>   binary you will be using to run PHP scripts in this environment.

When I do this, it says `/usr/bin/php`. So, I have put `zf.sh` and `zf.php` into `/usr/bin`.

Now, the next step is where I get really confused.

> The next order of business is to ensure that Zend Framework library is
>   set up correctly inside of the system PHP include_path. To find out
>   where your include_path is located, you can execute php -i and look
>   for the include_path variable, or more succinctly, execute php -i |
>   grep include_path. Once you have found where your include_path is
>   located (this will generally be something like /usr/lib/php,
>   /usr/share/php, /usr/local/lib/php, or similar), ensure that the
>   contents of the /library/ directory are put inside your include_path
>   specified directory.

Running `php -i | grep include_path` returns `include_path => .: => .:`, which I am not really sure what means (I am new to *nix). I have tried to copy the contents of the `library` folder to `/usr/share/php/`, but without luck.

So I guess my problem is figuring out where my include path is so I can put the contents of the library folder there. I figured I would find my php.ini. When I run `phpinfo()` from a script, it says that my php.ini is located at `/etc`, but there is no php.ini in that folder. Also, executing `php -i` shows the following:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

I guess my PHP is running with default settings since no config file is loaded. I am testing from the terminal with `zf show version` and get `-bash: zf: command not found`.

I am really, really confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems once. If i remember correctly i was using WAMP and it had multiple php.ini files (3 i think), i had to track down the right one.

i followed this tutorial and it worked for me
http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, that worked after figuring out to put/create `.bash_profile` in the home folder (/Users/Andy).